# How to solve Rails/RedundantPresenceValidationOnBelongsTo offense detected without rubocop autofix (which breaks the code)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubocop

I have some work which doesn't touch the file in question but due to some rubocop update it's now showing:

> Rails/RedundantPresenceValidationOnBelongsTo: Remove explicit presence
> validation for creator

Which later mentions is auto-correctable but using autofix breaks the code

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve this by doing two things:

1. Adding the file path to the your rubocop file

```
    Lint/RedundantCopDisableDirective:
      Exclude:
         - 'path/to/my/file.rb'
```

2. Wrap the offending lines around with disable and enable comments

```
    # rubocop:disable Rails::SkipsModelValidations
    validates :something,        presence:  true, on: :create
    # rubocop:enable Rails::SkipsModelValidations
```